Is there any way to use code in lstlisting with utf8 characters?
I have code embedded in LaTeX containing a UTF-8 character like a greek letter.
In many modern languages this is perfectly legal, but LaTeX hates it.
is there any way to include a source code file and not have to hand-edit the text?
I am hoping for some option that:
lstinputlisting[language=java]{code/mycode.js}

and that I don't have to change the code. Currently the only letter is greek μ and it is in a string: "μg". I temporarily fixed the problem by using "ug" but that required changing the code.

see listingsutf8 package
